# JQuery generating elements that are siblings and then appending all at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

There have been a few situations where I'm trying to generate content, but the elements are siblings. So, I want to generate tags that are siblings, and then just append 1 element to the actual DOM to reduce DOM calls.

For example (starting with element generation):

```
var tr = $('<tr>');
var td = $('<td>')
                .append( $('<label>Label 1</label>') )
                .append( "some text" );
tr.append(td);

var tr2 = $('<tr>');
var td2 = $('<td>')
                .append( $('<label>Label 2</label>') )
                .append( "other text" );
tr2.append(td2);
```

This would generate something that looks like this for the first tr element:

```
<tr>
     <td>
          <label>Labe 1</label>
          some text
     </td>
</tr>
```

and the second element would look similar. This is fine, but my question is is there a way to add the second  to the first  and then only have to append the first  to the actual table in the dom?

Looking to do something like:

```
$('#someTable').append( /*append 1 thing instead of both tr's*/ );
```

The idea is to reduce calls to the actual DOM, if there are tons of elements.

Note: I realize that document.createElement is way faster than $('create element')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `add` to create a new collection containing the elements from both collections.  For instance:

```
tr = tr.add(tr2);
```

After this, `tr` would now contain both rows.  You could then append them at once:

```
$("#someTable").append(tr);  // add all rows contained in tr
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried this but when you console.log(tr.html()); it only shows the first element and its sub elements. Is this because .html() only shows the inner elements?

Comment: Sorry, updated answer.  `add` returns a new collection and doesn't affect the original collection apparently.

Comment: oh yah, you are right. .after and .insertAfter don't seem to help either

Comment: Depending on your situation, you could also just generate a string with the html and append that all at once.

Comment: Yeah, true, but my feeling is that the strings tend to be less wieldy when the code generation gets really large

Comment: `add` will work with my updated answer.  Though maybe you can create and append a `tbody`?  (depending on your specifics)

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of achieving this. I would suggest the preferred method is to use [detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) on your table, do your DOM manipulation (add a bunch of `<tr>`s), then re-add it to your DOM. This is actually the method described in [jquery performance](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/detach-elements-before-work-with-them/).

## Note:

I had originally suggested using [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) or [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) as solutions for this question, but one of the OP's requirements is to avoid creating an "intermediate" parent. Both of these methods are therefore not valid solutions. I have since improved the above solution.

Comment: I don't think `after` will work when the elements don't have a parent element at all.

Comment: detatch looks like it might be the best solution. insertAfter/after would reduce the DOM calls, if you did it after building each tr and then adding it to the actual element, but I'm looking for a solution that wouldn't require a parent element, as james said.

Comment: AFAIK detach is specifically for doing what you want, removing an element from the DOM to manipulate.

Comment: @JamesMontagne It looks like you're correct about `after`.

Answer (score 0):

Since ideally tr elements are children of tbody you could add all tr's to tbody then finally add the one tbody to the table:

```
var tbody = $('<tbody/>');
tbody.append( tr )
.append( tr2 );
```